Бот отправляет несколько сообщений в ЛС, с паузами между отправкой, новым кодписчикам канала
Когда несколько пользователей подписываются на канал, бот отправляет часть сообщений
from aiogram.utils.chat_action import ChatActionSender
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardButton
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from asyncio import gather, run
from storages import *
import logging
import asyncio


bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher()

inline_button = InlineKeyboardButton(text="Подписаться", url="https://t.me/+ouYL3ISpgQxiMjVi")
board = [[inline_button]]
menu = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard=board)


@dp.chat_join_request()
async def start(update: types.ChatJoinRequest):
    print("[New client][ID] --> ", update.from_user.id)
    await update.approve()
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=update.from_user.id, text=first_message)
    await sender(update.from_user.id)


async def sender(id_chat):
    await asyncio.sleep(first_video_duration)
    await send_video(id_chat, first_video_path)

    await asyncio.sleep(second_video_duration)
    await send_video(id_chat, second_video_path)

    await asyncio.sleep(third_video_duration)
    await send_video(id_chat, third_video_path)

    await asyncio.sleep(fourth_video_duration)
    await send_video(id_chat, fourth_video_path)

    await asyncio.sleep(fifth_video_duration)
    await send_video(id_chat, fifth_video_path)

    await asyncio.sleep(sixth_video_duration)
    await send_video(id_chat, sixth_video_path)

    await asyncio.sleep(seventh_video_duration)
    await send_video(id_chat, seventh_video_path)

    await send_video(id_chat, final_video_path)


async def send_video(id_chat, path):
    async with ChatActionSender.upload_video(chat_id=id_chat, bot=bot):
        if path == final_video_path:
            await bot.send_video_note(chat_id=id_chat,
                                      video_note=types.FSInputFile(path=path),
                                      reply_markup=menu)
        else:
            await bot.send_video_note(chat_id=id_chat,
                                      video_note=types.FSInputFile(path=path))


async def launch_bot():
    await dp.start_polling(bot)


async def main():
    await gather(
        launch_bot()
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run(main())

Бот отправляет несколько видео-кружочков в ЛС при подписке, делая паузы между сообщениями. Но при подписке одновременно нескольких клиентов, возникает следующая ошибка
Cause exception while process update id=533293884 by bot id=7388211844
TelegramNetworkError: HTTP Client says - Request timeout error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/aiogram/client/session/aiohttp.p                                              y", line 170, in make_request
    async with session.post(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1197, i                                              n __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 507, in                                               _request
    with timer:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/aiohttp/helpers.py", line 735, i                                              n __exit__
    raise asyncio.TimeoutError from None
TimeoutError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py                                              ", line 309, in _process_update
    response = await self.feed_update(bot, update, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py                                              ", line 158, in feed_update
    response = await self.update.wrap_outer_middleware(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/middlewares/e                                              rror.py", line 25, in __call__
    return await handler(event, data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/middlewares/u                                              ser_context.py", line 49, in __call__
    return await handler(event, data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/aiogram/fsm/middleware.py", line                                               42, in __call__
    return await handler(event, data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/event/telegra                                              m.py", line 121, in trigger
    return await wrapped_inner(event, kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/event/handler                                              .py", line 43, in call
    return await wrapped()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py                                              ", line 276, in _listen_update
    return await self.propagate_event(update_type=update_type, event=event, **kw                                              args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                              ^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/router.py", l                                              ine 142, in propagate_event
    return await observer.wrap_outer_middleware(_wrapped, event=event, data=kwar                                              gs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                              ^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/router.py", l                                              ine 137, in _wrapped
    return await self._propagate_event(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/router.py", l                                              ine 162, in _propagate_event
    response = await observer.trigger(event, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/event/telegra                                              m.py", line 121, in trigger
    return await wrapped_inner(event, kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/event/handler                                              .py", line 43, in call
    return await wrapped()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/39/main.py", line 23, in start
    await sender(update.from_user.id)
  File "/root/39/main.py", line 28, in sender
    await send_video(id_chat, first_video_path)
  File "/root/39/main.py", line 58, in send_video
    await bot.send_video_note(chat_id=id_chat,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/aiogram/client/bot.py", line 332                                              2, in send_video_note
    return await self(call, request_timeout=request_timeout)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/aiogram/client/bot.py", line 480                                              , in __call__
    return await self.session(self, method, timeout=request_timeout)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/aiogram/client/session/base.py",                                               line 254, in __call__
    return cast(TelegramType, await middleware(bot, method))
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/aiogram/client/session/aiohttp.p                                              y", line 175, in make_request
    raise TelegramNetworkError(method=method, message="Request timeout error")
aiogram.exceptions.TelegramNetworkError: HTTP Client says - Request timeout error                                         

Неопытный еще, поэтому буду благодарен подробному объяснению, заранее спасибо!
